# Knife upload error - cannot have a child created under it

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to upload a recipe and chef is reporting this error ". cannot have a child created under it" when I run `knife upload test.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't upload a single recipe, you have to upload the whole cookbook.